# Should I change the title in my passport to Dr. after getting PhD

Tags: phd, titles

In many places, a title column is asked where I fill Mr. After getting my PhD can I "officially" change it to Dr.? Is this country dependent? I want to know about India, DrUK and US.

Comment: You can still sign a document with Mr/Ms/Mrs/etc. even if you passport says "Dr.". - As a general rule, I would recommend using the title only where it is (academically) appropriate (e.g. application for a research position, conference) but not where it would be simply boasting (e.g. hotel/airline reservations).

Comment: @DetlevCM: Well, there's always the places where people might belittle you, and having a Ph.D. might prevent that. I have a friend in Germany and she told me that it was very hard for her to find an apartment, until she got her Ph.D. and once people see "Dr." as the official title, it is far far easier to find an apartment. (And this difficulty is partially corroborated by a different friend who wanted to live in Germany for a while, and went there with literally huge wads of cash, but still got denied by some landlords because he didn't have a stable job.)

Comment: I heard, in Germany, that if you have a PhD then you expected to update your passport. I'm not 100% sure thu.

Comment: @TheGuy: You can, but you don't have to.

Comment: @TheGuy You have to get a new passport every few years anyway, so you are a lot cheaper off by waiting until you have to get a new one because the old one expired.

Comment: @Inkblot I'd say if people belittle another person for not having a PhD, it says more about them than the PhD-holder, especially as an impressive academic title or job title means very little nowadays. (There are good and bad professors, PhDs are a "dime a dozen" nowadays... and everybody can be the director of their own business.) Then again, it does remind me of an article from zeit/zeitOnline a long time ago about the Austrian love for titles, where being "professor so and so" might get you a table in a restaurant, but being "mr so and so" does not.

Comment: @DetlevCM: That is a gross misinterpretation of what I was saying. Nobody is belittling you for *not* having a PhD, rather they *don't* belittle you for *having* one.

Comment: @Inkblot Well, the alternative word to use then would be discriminate against non-academics. The result is the same. You have people who actively think people without a specific academic degree to be below them/not worthy of renting/etc. and are thus discriminated against. - And as I said before, this says more about the person applying the discrimination.

Comment: Obviously, the practice differs in different countries. Would you not tag the one you have in mind?

Answer (score 14):

PhD is an academic degree. It is actually dependent on person and country whether to use the title "Dr." in passports and other relevant documents.

However, using Mr. would be wise to avoid a confusion between a doctor (MBBS, MD) and a doctorate (PhD). As per UK gov website, it is not advisable [[1]](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/118548/titles-included-in-passports.pdf)

I have never come across anyone using Dr. in legal documents. Moreover, it is not really a necessity to include Dr. in official/legal documents. For example, I still see my supervisor (who is a senior professor with PhD in 1990s) gets official documents with his name titled "Mr.".

Comment: Even MBBS is an academic degree only no? They can put Dr on their passports, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. That is why it should not be used.

Comment: "I have never come across anyone using Dr. in legal documents." - it's not unusual here in Germany, and it sometimes gives you a bit of an advantage when dealing with banks and similar (in that they (irrationally, I'd say) assume they can give you a higher credit allowance etc.).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Oh, I didn't know about Germany. This is quite interesting. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Coder: If neither PhDs not medics can use Dr in title, why is it a title in the first place?

Comment: @vassalraja Of course they can use the title. Thats what they have earned after several years of dedicated research and studies. But, is it really a necessity to include them in official/legal documents? As I said it depends on individual preference and place of stay. I still see my supervisor (who is a senior professor with PhD in 1990s) gets official documents with his name titled "Mr.".

Comment: The link you provided says that professional titles such as Doctor are acceptable without limiting it to medical doctors. It merely says that academic and professional qualifications are not allowed. So you can't have "PhD" or "MD" in your UK passport, but you can have Doctor/Dr. included as an observation.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Even more so, for better or worse, here in Austria, where people even sign with their MA.

Comment: I agree with JAB, perhaps @Coder can edit if they agree.

Comment: I'm down voting because the line you wrote about the UK gov guideline is not true. If you edit accordingly, please tag me and I may upvote.

Comment: I agree with the @JAB, user2768 and The Doctor on the misinterpretation of the rules in the linked document. On my reading the rules forbidding academic qualifications refer to the post nomnial letters, e.g. BSc, BA, BEng. The title of Doctor, bestowed upon completion of a PhD or simmilar, is allowed as a professional title. The PhD is differnet to other academic qualifications as it gives you an academic qualification AND a change in title.

Comment: That said, I don't think titles appear on passports in Australia.

Answer (score 8):

As far as the USA, their passports do not have a title field  for marital status (Miss, Mrs) professional titles (Dr, Rev, etc) or for titles or nobility (Dame, Sir, etc) so it’s a moot point for American passport holders.

Comment: For what it's worth, titles are not entered on Irish passports either.

Comment: Nor in italian ones

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on you whether you use Dr. or not. Getting a PhD is a very important and difficult accomplishment and you should feel proud of it. If you want to use Dr in any circumstance including in your passport (if allowed) go for it. If you don't feel like it then don't. I don't get why people would be worried about being confused with a MD A MD is a Dr just like anybody else, it has no higher or lesser importance. If someone gets confused then they can ask you what you are a Doctor of. My suggestion is use it whenever you feel like it, you worked really hard for it.