# Is Mx. the default title for Male non-phd holders?

Tags: titles, gender

A journal drop-down menu for selecting a person's title has four options but none of them are *Mr.*

[image]

(I definitely scrolled down enough.)

As a male, non-PhD holder should I select *Mx.*, or is this a mistake by the journal?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Mx = maxwells, unit of flux.

Comment: All this fuss when the obvious answer was "ask the journal".

Comment: @Najib Idrissi I learned something from the question.

Comment: As noted in an answer, Mx is gender-neutral. Allowing Ms but not Mr is probably a mistake. You could query it if you care, or you could select Mx.

Comment: @henning I'm more talking about all the speculation below on whether Ms is actual MSc or something.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi - Certainly no question the form is very poorly designed. :-)

Comment: I think required these title questions are ridiculous, especially in academic contexts. I always select either “Miss” or “His Holiness”.

Comment: For what it's worth, are you sure this is a real journal? It seems likely that such a problem would have been caught and fixed long ago for a real journal and would only persist on a predatory/fake one. It might even be a filter, like the bad grammar in Nigerian prince scams, to drive away submissions from people who'd quickly realize it's a scam.

Comment: "Mx"... looks to me like a gender-neutral alternative to "Mr./Ms."

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Mx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mx_(title)) is a gender-neutral honorific.  It's probably not a typo.

Dr would typically be used if you have a doctoral degree, and Prof if you are employed in a professor-like capacity (it means different things in different countries, but generally any semi-permanent faculty job is reasonably included).  Otherwise, you can decide which of Ms and Mx fits you better.

If you feel that there isn't an option that's appropriate for you, you can take it up with the journal.

Comment: Not including Mr. does seem like an oversight, especially since Ms. is included.

Comment: @Thomas - indeed, be gender neutral if one wants, but to put up Ms. and Mx. as the two options seems to negate gender neutral status for Mx.

Comment: Ms. is not gender neutral and is female in its inference in English, however, it is possible in some countries that this is not the case.

Comment: Or this is the deepest act of chauvanism ever and men are assumed to all have PhDs?

Comment: @Thomas Ms. is likely for the masters degree, not for the gender.

Comment: @Polygnome I disagree (see my comment on the answer by somethingsomething).

Comment: I read "gender-neutral horrific", kinda fits too though.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm sorry but I disagree. MSc is strictly for masters of Science, while Ms. is the fairly common shorthand for Masters (of all kinds) and Bs. the common shorthand for Bachelors degrees. Wikipedia lists MS or M.S. as shorthands for a masters title as well. Maybe this is a cultural thing, since we do not know anything about the county of origin of the journal, and some of the abbreviations might be more or less popular depending on where you live.

Comment: @Polygnome "Master" is not a title in the same way Dr. and Mr. are.

Comment: NB: in Dutch, *Mr.* is the title for a Master of Laws (M.L., L.L.M.)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Why wouldn't it? Its an academic title just as Dr. or Dipl.-Ing.

Comment: @Polygnome As far as I am aware, it is not, no. Getting a master's degree does not mean people ought to refer to you as master lastname (as cool as that would be).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft its not *common* to actually use an Ms(c) title, but it was quite common for Dipl. and Dipl.-Ings. to use them. But there is no difference. If you want to be known as Msc Lastname you can be. I've even seen letterheads with bachelors degrees in some organizations.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - Cool as long as your surname isn't Bates. *(He said, lowering the tone...)* ;-)

Comment: @Polygnome That's a very, very country specific thing. In Austria at least for a very long time "Dr." was part of your name, while "Dipl.Ing" and co weren't. Meaning you didn't have to list your engineering degree on official documentation, but had to list Dr. That hasn't been the law for a few decades now though, but similar things probably exist/existed in many European countries.

Comment: @Voo I've never heard of a title being *required*, and [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/93419/39577) also contradicts that. You are not allowed to use any title you have not earned, but omitting titles is usually always allowed.

Comment: @Polygnome How exactly does an answer about the **UK** contradict an answer that tells you how the law is different between countries and then gives an example about **Austria**? [Here's some article that talks about the history in Austria](https://www.wienerzeitung.at/meinungen/glossen/261347_Ist-Doktor-ein-Teil-des-Namens.html), I doubt you'll find much information about the history of Austrian laws in English if you don't speak German though.

Comment: @Voo OP has still not said where the journal is based, so assuming any one culture is futile. In my very second comment I already said that this is likely culture dependent, so pointing out that there are multiple cultures where Ms is indeed the valid title for masters degrees seems highly relevant here.

Comment: @Voo furthermore, your article exactly makes my point. "as war bis 1966 so. Seither ist es beispielsweise jedem Dr. phil. freigestellt, ob er ein Schriftstück mit "Dr." oder ohne "Dr." unterfertigt, ob er im Reisepass, im Führerschein den Doktor stehen hat oder nicht.". You are not required to use the title and may omit it. Exactly as I said, even is Austria.

Comment: @Polygnome I said exactly that if you read my comment ("hasn't been the cast for decades"). The point still is that there was at least one legislation in which one specific academic title was part of your name while most others aren't. As you rightfully said the OP hasn't specified the legislation, so certainly this could still be the case in some other region.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Actually, Master *is* a title: it is the title for a male who is not yet old enough to be Mr.

Comment: @Polygnome Wikipedia lists MS as an abbreviation for the title of the *degree*, not as the title of a person. It says MS is used in the US, where holding a masters degree does not give you a title. Post-nominal letters are not titles.

Comment: Using "Master" as an academic title in speech is awkward for several reasons—it's use as a title for pre-pubescent males in recent historical times, it's use as a title for Masters in the skilled trades, and (at least in the US) most importantly it's lingering suggestion of institutionalized slavery. Yikes!  Personally I woudn't touch it.

Comment: @JessicaB It's also a title for some men in the BDSM community, but that's neither here nor there in this context. (&, for what it's worth, "master" as a title for young gentlemen is archaic to the point of roleplaying these days.)

Comment: @lly Err.. not it's not. Boys are still called master, if something is required.

Comment: @JessicaB Yeah, I got from your initial comment that you weren't aware. [Even the OED knows this is archaic to rare now](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114751). It's really not a thing anymore, except among people pretending they're living at an 18th century boarding school. If you've got to give a boy a title, you just go with Mr and move on.

Comment: @lly My basis for believing that it is used is that I have seen it being used. Therefore, it is still in use.

Comment: One of my grandmothers used to address envelopes containing letters to me using "Master McKee" in the 1970s and 80s. But her habits in such matters were set around the Great Depression, so while I consider it historical it doesn't speak to me of pre-Victorian times.

Comment: @dmckee [It should](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Master+Williams%2CMaster+Johnson%2C+Master+Edwards&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3). More recent usage have been archaisms *and* usually in reference to slave, mason, &c. masters rather than upper-class boys. JessicaB is an example of someone who still upholds the custom and there were even more holdouts in the '30s, doubtless, but it's not a normal thing and hasn't been for awhile.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well, people insist on calling me magistr(=magister,mistr,master) all the time because they see the Mgr. in front of the name (required by the university, I wouldn't include it myself) all the time. Often, They ignore the PhD., because it is behind the name...  But our country is silly, we have even people actively using the BC. title and wanting to be called batchelors... And the extremely weird "ittle doctorate" thing.

Answer (score 28):

Since no one else answered your actual questions:

> Is Mx. the default title for [m]ale non-[P]h[D] holders?

## No,

it is not. It's a recent gender-neutral form of the usual English titles Mr/Mrs/Miss/Ms which might be allowed for those not wishing to signal or accept a binary gender. It's not standard, and Mr. remains much more common. More common still would be for an untitled person to simply be untitled.

*This* use seems bizarre to the point of inviting a sex-discrimination lawsuit. They require that you provide a title, with lower-level academics forced to declare themselves *either* female *or* other. The only rationale for such a setup besides trolling (cismen who complain have their applications filed circularly) would be if they intend to assign extra credit to applications by self-declared women.

> As a male... non-PhD holder should I select Mx... or is this a mistake by the journal?

**Yes**, you should select it if you plan to continue your application, despite knowing your gender will probably hurt your chances.

Comment: Or they meant to remove all gendered options and forgot one of them...

Comment: I don't really see anything in Nate's answer that disagrees with me here, as he does not make any guesses about why Ms is there while Mr is not.

Comment: -1 for the gratuitous rant that they're going to "discriminate against men" without any evidence. It's more likely that they wrongly deemed Prof.  a masculine honorific applicable to any non-PhD-holding man in this context, and for the recommendation to choose Mx if it's not a title the OP uses.

Comment: @R.. **You're welcome to prove my point** by circular binning my post while going on a gratuitous rant about a straightforward analysis, but you'd get further by suggesting any alternative reason for such an obviously sexist *required* field in your own answer to OP.

Comment: (No, "Ms" for "Master of Science" is not remotely plausible, pending some thorough evidence of its use in some other language that led to its appearance here.)

Comment: "*They require that you provide a title, with lower-level academics forced to declare themselves either female or other.*" I'd vote this up multiple times if I could :3

Answer (score 1):

Based on the context, the options most likely are:

- Dr: Doctor (PhD)
- Ms: usually written MSc (master of science)
- Prof: Professor
- Mx: Ms/Mr/x (no academic degree/title)

So you would fall either under Ms or Mx depending on your level of education.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. These are titles, not degrees, so MSc would also not be a possible option. And I don't see any reason to assume that this journal would include specifically MSc (spelled in a massively incorrect way) and not other master's degrees, such as MA.

Comment: While not the accepted answer (and something I had not considered on looking at the list originally), I think this is probably the correct interpretation.

Comment: Do you imply that  MA (master of arts) can not send manuscript to the journal?

Comment: @scaaahu I think that any interpretation of the list will lead to some offense, for example why would they have Ms and not Mr ? Perhaps Ms is not strictly MSc but is meant as "MasterS" of either arts or science?  It's clearly a poorly chosen set of options though.

Comment: @Christophe My comment above was not directed to you, it was meant for the OP of the answer.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft According to wikipedia MSc can also be spelled MS, which might be automatically converted to Ms by some crappy frontend. 

Depending on which field this is, I don't think MA/MBA/... are very likely to be considered as possible authors.

But there's no doubt that it is very unclear and incomplete regardless of what they are trying to achieve.

Comment: The possibility of bad conversion does not explain why the list of titles would include a degree.

Comment: It most certainly makes little sense, but I'd consider the odds to be way higher than them explicitely putting the female and a neutral honorific there, while forgetting about Mr.

Comment: We don't know what field the OP of the question is in, so we don't know if MA/MBA holders are not likely to send manuscripts. I think your answer will make sense if you say MS  means Masters degree holder (i.e. take out master of science)

Comment: It's a good thought, but the field is clearly for a *title*, and I can't find any evidence of "Ms." as a *title* for someone with a master's degree, at all. And my, wouldn't it be confusing (given the other meaning of the title "Ms.").

Comment: This is desperate reaching

Answer (score 1):

I personally understand it like this:

1. Dr => Doctors (PhD, medicine.. we czechs have Mudr, PaeDr, etc.)
2. Ms => Masters (of Science, Art, Business, etc)
3. Mx => Gender specific (Mr, Ms, Mrs)
4. Prof => Professors (and maybe candidates?)

I do not necessarily see it as a flaw per se as it seems logical to divide per earned title. Just a bit unclear spec..

It is flawed by the idea of having Ms understood as Miss instead of M-s, but other than this it is completely logical!

**Small advice:**

Tell the official to clear things out by giving a hint.

Comment: "Ms" is not being understood as "Miss", it is being understood as "Ms", which is a common title (at least where I come from) for women who do not want to signal their marital status.

I have never seen Ms used as a title for "somebody who holds a masters degree", though I guess it is possible that is used that way somewhere...

Comment: 'it seems logical to divide per earned title': except that you do not acquire a new title for a masters. Ms is the title for some women, and absolutely nothing to do with academia.